# Как можно вывести 2 случайных элемента массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, случайные-числа

```
export const ratingScreen = app.screen('/rating', async (ctx, req) => {

  let records = await ImagesTable.findAll(ctx, {
    where:{
      sessionId: ctx.session.id
    }
  });

  return (
    <screen title="Rating picture">
      <box style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        {records.map((record, index) => {
          if (index < 2) {
            return (
              <box key={index} style={{ flex: 1, padding: 6, backgroundColor: 'lightblue',     marginHorizontal: 4, marginTop: 6 }}>
                <list-item
                  style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}
                  icon={{url: record.image.getThumbnailUrl(100)}}
                  content={{
                    title: record.filename,
                    subTitle: record.createdAt.toLocaleDateString(),
                  }}
                />
              </box> 
            )
          }
        } 
        )}
      </box>
    </screen>
  )
});
```

Пока что у меня получается вывести только 2 первых элемента.
Также в (index < 2) я пробовал (index < Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)), но так отрисовывается разное количество элементов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить 2 алгоритма чтобы достать из массива рандомные элементы:

- ##### Алгоритм где нужно проверять был ли уже выдан этот случайный индекс:

  1. Объявляем вспомогательную функцию `getRandomIndex`, который будет выдывать рандомное целое значение в отрезке `[0, max - 1]`
  2. Перед началом проверям на правильность количества треуемых элементов:

     2.1. Оно не может быть больше чем длина самого массива, т.к. мы достаём уникальные рандомные элементы, а значит максимум можно достать все элементы массива

     2.2. Оно не может быть меньше чем 1, по очевидным причинам

     2.3. Оно должно быть целым числом, по очевидным причинам
  3. Объявляем пустой [набор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), куда будем записывать все наши раномные индексы. У набора есть очень полезное в данном случае свойство, при добавлении элемента, который уже там есть, он его не добавляет, таким образом мы точно можем быть уверены, что там все индексы будут уникальными
  4. Заполняем набор рандомными индексами пока его размер не станет равным `count`
  5. Преобразуем набор в массив с помощью [синтаксиса spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
  6. С помошью метода [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) преобразуем массив рандомных индексов в массив рандомных элементов

  ```js
  const nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];

  const getRandomIndex = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

  const getRandomElements = (array, count) => {
    const isCountMoreThanArrayLength = count > array.length;
    const isCountLessThanOne = count < 1;
    const isCountInteger = Math.round(count) === count;
    
    if (isCountMoreThanArrayLength || isCountLessThanOne || !isCountInteger) return [];
    
    const usedIndexes = new Set();
    
    while (usedIndexes.size !== count) {
      usedIndexes.add(getRandomIndex(array.length));
    }
    
    return [...usedIndexes].map(index => array[index]);
  }

  console.log(getRandomElements(nums, 2));
  console.log(getRandomElements(nums, 4));
  ```
- ##### Алгоритм без проверки был ли уже выдан этот случайный индекс:

  1. Объявляем вспомогательную функцию `getRandomIndex`, который будет выдывать рандомное целое значение в отрезке `[0, max - 1]`
  2. Перед началом проверям на правильность количества треуемых элементов:

     2.1. Оно не может быть больше чем длина самого массива, т.к. мы достаём уникальные рандомные элементы, а значит максимум можно достать все элементы массива

     2.2. Оно не может быть меньше чем 1, по очевидным причинам

     2.3. Оно должно быть целым числом, по очевидным причинам
  3. Создаём массив неиспользованных индексов с помощью [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) ([Пример из документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from))
  4. Достаём рандомный индекс
  5. Удаляем его из массива неиспользованных индексов с помощью [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) и записываем [этот элемент](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value) в переменную `randomIndex`
  6. Записываем в массив рандомных элементов элемент, который стоит в оригинальном массиве на месте `randomIndex`
  7. Повторяем пункты 4-6 пока длина массива не станет равной `count`

  ```js
  const nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];

  const getRandomIndex = (length) => Math.floor(Math.random() * length);

  const getRandomElements = (array, count) => {
    const isCountMoreThanArrayLength = count > array.length;
    const isCountLessThanOne = count < 1;
    const isCountInteger = Math.round(count) === count;
    
    if (isCountMoreThanArrayLength || isCountLessThanOne || !isCountInteger) return [];
    
    const unusedIndexes = Array.from(array, (v, i) => i);
    const randomElements = [];
    
    while (randomElements.length !== count) {
      const randomUnusedIndex = getRandomIndex(unusedIndexes.length);
      const randomIndex = unusedIndexes.splice(randomUnusedIndex, 1)[0];
      
      randomElements.push(array[randomIndex]);
    }
    
    return randomElements;
  }

  console.log(getRandomElements(nums, 2));
  console.log(getRandomElements(nums, 4));
  ```

---

Достатки первого алгоритма:

- Все операции достаточно быстрые
- Чем меньше будет количество нужных рандомных элементов и/или больше размер исходного массива тем быстрее будет работать

Недостатки первого алгоритма:

- Если из массива понадобится достаточно больше количество рандомных элементов (например есть массив на 100 элементов и нам нужно 95 уникальных рандомных элемента), то алгоритм может работать очень долго. Проблема в том, что чем больше уникальных элементов мы рандомно достаём, тем меньше шанс в следующий раз достать опять уникальный элемент и надо ждать пока нам повезёт и попадёт рандомный элемент, который мы не использовали
- В связи с предыдущим недостатком вытекает этот недостаток - невозможно оценить время работы алгоритма. Каждый запуск - это лотерея

---

Достатки второго алгоритма

- Всегда сразу берём неиспользованный рандомный элемент не теряя время на ненужные итерации
- Всегда работает за определённое количество времени. Имею ввиду что сложность алгоритма постоянна при любых наборах данных

Недостатки второго алгоритма:

- Операции медленные и чем длинне будет входной массив тем дольше будет работать алгоритм вначале. Это связанно с тем, что мы создаём массив индексов, длина которой напрямую зависит от длины входного массива. Метод `splice` так же будет работать медленне вначале, т.к. при удалении из середины массива элемента все последующие надо переиндексовывать, чтобы массив был цельным

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно вывести 2 случайных элемента массива?

Например так

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
console.log(test(arr, 2))

//
function test(arr, n) {
  if (!n || arr.length < n) return null
  const os = new Set()
  const a = []
  do {
    // берем случайный номер от 0 до длины массива
    const i = Math.trunc(Math.random() * arr.length)
    // проверяем не брали ли уже такой
    if (os.has(i)) continue
    // запоминаем что взяли
    os.add(i)
    a.push(arr[i])
  } while (os.size < n)
  return a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример компонента, который выводит 2 случайных элемента массива:

```
const arrayData = [
  {id: 1, value: 'раз ромашка'},
  {id: 2, value: 'два ромашка'},
  {id: 3, value: 'три ромашка'},
  {id: 4, value: 'а я четырую сорвал'},
  {id: 5, value: 'пять ромашка'},
  {id: 6, value: 'шесть ромашка'},
  {id: 7, value: 'семь, просто семь'},
]

const Rnd = () => {
  const [dataArray, setAr] = useState(arrayData);

  const rndArr = () => {
    const rnd = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <=1; i++) {
      rnd.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * dataArray.length))    
    }
    return rnd;
  }

  const idxses = rndArr();

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {dataArray
          .filter((it, idx) => idxses.includes(idx))
          .map(item => <span>{item.id} - {item.value} {' '}</span>)}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```